# how to upload multiple Image in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to upload multiple images in my Django project, but it is not working. Although, I have tried many things but there is no error.

My HTML FILE

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="photo" id="photo" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" onchange="readFile(this);" multiple>
```

My Models

```
class MyGeneralModel(models.Model):
    some_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    .....
```

Here I am generating dynamic file name.

```
def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.image_for.some_name
    slug = slugify(title)
    unique_slug = slug
    return "scammer_images/%s-%s" % (unique_slug, filename)
```

Here is my Image Model.

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image_for = models.ForeignKey(MyGeneralModel, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename, verbose_name='Image',blank=True, null=True)
```

And my views.py is here. The variable get is the instance of MyGeneralModel.

```
for file in request.FILES.getlist('photo'):
    instance = Images.objects.create(image_for=get,image=file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form. So, the request.FILES return empty dict. Now, I solved it.